# How to find last number in row minus second to last number in row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that I'm using to try and keep track of google keyword rankings, but I can't figure out how to track the last change in keyword ranking, meaning the last cell in the row MINUS the second to last cell in the row. I've included a picture on what I'm trying to accomplish. The formula would take, for example, in J3-I3 to get the last change of 4 shown in D3.

Right now I have this code:

```
=(LOOKUP(2,1/(3:3>0),3:3))-LOOKUP(9E+300,B3:INDEX(B3:J3,MATCH(9E+300,B3:J3)-1))
```

Which is fine, but I need to keep changing the cell references is. Is there any easier way to accomplish this?

[image: photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just INDEX(MATCH()) and refer to the full row.

```
=INDEX(3:3,MATCH(1E+99,3:3))-INDEX(3:3,MATCH(1E+99,3:3)-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have, say, 12 columns B="Jan" to M="Dec" with a formula in each, and you need to calculate the difference between the latest month's value and the previous month's value, the formula above does not work if any columns are blank but with formulas, or until you have a value for each of the 12 months.

If you want to calculate, say, Jun minus May when Jul to Dec are blank except for their formulas, this formula (for row 4) will do it for whatever the latest month with a numerical value is:

```
=INDEX(4:4,MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(B4:M4),COLUMN(B4:M4))))-OFFSET(B4,0,SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(B4:M4),1))-2,1,1)
```

It must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

@ScottCraner has provided an answer with the right logic, which is to

> locate the second last and last number in each row, and then perform a
>   simple subtraction between the two.

INDEX+MATCH is one way of solving the question, but in this case, given that all data are stored in a table, and to add the flexibility of

**1) moving the table around or across worksheets;**

**2) entering numeric value in the same row outside of the table;**

**without incurring errors,** I've used **OFFSET+COLUMNS** instead.

Please note in my example I have given a name to the table, called it **Tbl_WordRk**, and I have added some data (in the gray area) for testing purpose.

[image: New Example]

Basically, **OFFSET** works in similar logic as INDEX, with a known starting point (such as B3 in my example), it will find the value (or even a range of values) in another row or column as long as you know the relative position of the value compared to the starting point. For example, if your starting point is cell A1, the following OFFSET function will return the value in cell D8.

```
=OFFSET(A1,7,3) which is interpreted as 7 rows down and 3 columns to the right of cell A1
```

**COLUMNS** finds the total number of columns of a given range, which is perfect for finding a column position within a **table**. The following formula will return number **7** which is the total number of columns of the table in my example, but please note it is NOT the **relative column position** of the last column to cell B3.

```
=COLUMNS(Tbl_WordRk)
```

You need to add `-1` to the above formula to find the relative column number of the last column from B3. And therefore, adding `-2` will return the relative column position of the second last column from B3.

So the final formula in cell B3 in my example is

**`=OFFSET(B3,,(COLUMNS(Tbl_WordRk)-2))-OFFSET(B3,,(COLUMNS(Tbl_WordRk)-1))`**

Then you just drag it down to the last row.

Just one more advice on the conditional format of your example, I would prefer not to show a green upward arrow if there is no change in the word ranking. If you know how to edit an existing conditional formatting, here is how to set it:

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Cheers :)